# BLE Read sensor data through raspberry pi

Tags: javascript, python, bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to build an iot platform that takes the sensor data via smartwatch and pass to Raspberry pi (BLE Gateway) and sends to webserver. I used https://github.com/noble/noble JS, able to connect to watch and can see the characteristics and services but cannot get the data. This is how I wrote

```
const  noble = require('@abandonware/noble')
noble.on('stateChange', async (state) => {
 if (state === 'poweredOn') {
     await noble.startScanningAsync([], false);
 } else {
     noble.stopScanningAsync();
  }
});
noble.on('discover', async (peripheral) => {
 console.log(peripheral.id)
 if (peripheral.id === "xxxxxxxxxx") peripheral.connectAsync(() => {

     peripheral.discoverServices(['fff0'], async (e, services) => {
    
         services[0].discoverCharacteristics(['fff7'], async (e, characteristics) => {
             const chara = characteristics[0]
      
             chara.once('read', (data) => {
                  console.log(data);
              })
             chara.once('notify', async function (isNotification) {
                 console.log('Notification', isNotification);
             })

             chara.readAsync(async (error, data) => {
                 console.log(data);
             })

         })
     })
  })
})
```

I contacted the watch manufacturer and they told me that I have to pass the 16 byte data, so for example to get the battery i need to pass

```
   0x13 AA 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 CRC
```

But they never told me how to pass or which language to use. They told me to go through BLE protocol but this is bit confusing. Anyone has any idea, how this can be done? Do I need to use python to pass the 16-byte command and get response.
Thank you

Comment: What the watch manufacturer told you is to write to a characteristic in order to get the battery value. They should give you also the characteristic UID to make this operation. 

It doesn't matter the language you use, it's simply the BLE protocol you need to use.
I suggest you this [guide](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ArduinoBLE) that explain easily the BLE protocol

Comment: @fabik111, Thank you for the info. It is a Chinese watch. They provide two characteristics UUid , one to write data from phone to watch and vice versa.  I will go through the guide to be more clear on what I need to do.